# How to use expressjs with connect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-connect

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', routes.index);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I'm getting the error `Most middleware (like json) is no longer bundled with....`
I've `npm installed connect` in the same folder.
But how do i use it?

I couldn't find any combined tutorial on `connect & express`, they either talk about `connect` or `express`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [Express.js's middleware documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#middleware),

> As of 4.x, Express no longer depends on Connect. All of Express' previously included middleware are now in separate repos. Please view [the list of middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware). The only included middleware is now `express.static()`.

So, to use `json` middleware, you need to include the [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) in the `package.json` and then use like this

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: thank you, i wrote `app.use(require('method-override')())` and it says it couldn't find it?

Comment: @NestedWeb Did you include that in the `package.json`?

Comment: ok thank you all done, i'll accept your answer, i just started with expressjs today